# python re regular expression freezes processing on random text

Tags: python, python-re

I have troubles with using re.
There are 2 re:

```
re.findall(r'\w+@\w+.\w+', text)
re.findall(r'[\+0-9\-\(\)]{8,20}', text)
```

I have ~10000 texts. And this regular expressions freezes python on random text while processing!
It could be 4000 or 4299 or another one.
Texts processes sequently. So I have no ideas why it could be...
Help me, please)

Comment: You're potentially out of memory and it's starting to page = extremely slow. Have you checked system resources during this process? You will likely have to do it in batches

Comment: Do you save the results of `re.findall`? How large are your texts? What is the minimal example of code that reproduces the issue? Is it a simple loop over the files you have?

Comment: U might store the intermediate results into a file rather than keeping it in memory and complie the regex expression then use it.

Comment: Yes, it's as simple loop over text. And yes, I save result in list.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment, so I'll response as an answer.

What is your purpose with the regex?

Is the first for email address and the second for phone number?

The second regex matches something like `+9-()+8-()...`

Try your regex here: https://regex101.com/

Or you can print out evey 10th or 20th line of text to find out which text failed.